# How to add new line in a string at a particular character number in python?

Tags: python

Input Received:

```
Line: agrgb This is a good planet
Line: 4f1g6 I like toast
Line: ew5je I like horseriding
```

How can I add a new line before each comment in the output.

```
Line: agrgb
This is a good plant
Line: 4f1g6
I like toast
Line: ew5je
I like horseriding
```

Comment: Please add your code in question

Comment: Is the location to put the new line fixed for every line?

Comment: Yes. Location is fixed. Just after a username and a space character.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
Input = ['Line: agrgb This is a good planet', 'Line: 4f1g6 I like toast', 'Line: ew5je I like horseriding']
for i in Input:
    split = i.split()
    print(' '.join(i for i in split[:2]))
    print(' '.join(i for i in split[2:]))
```

Output:

```
Line: agrgb
This is a good planet
Line: 4f1g6
I like toast
Line: ew5je
I like horseriding
```

And if `Input` is a single string you can convert it to the list shown above like this:

```
Input = 'Line: agrgb This is a good planet Line: 4f1g6 I like toast Line: ew5je I like horseriding'
Input = [f'Line:{i}' for i in Input.split('Line:') if i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `re.sub`

```py
import re

data = """
Line: agrgb This is a good planet
Line: 4f1g6 I like toast
Line: ew5je I like horseriding
"""

out = re.sub(r'(Line: [^ ]*) (.*)', r'\1\n\2', data)
```

```
print(out)

Line: agrgb
This is a good planet
Line: 4f1g6
I like toast
Line: ew5je
I like horseriding
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```py
text = """Line: agrgb This is a good planet
Line: 4f1g6 I like toast
Line: ew5je I like horseriding"""

result = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    line_header, that_number, comment = line.split(maxsplit=2)
    result.append(f"{line_header} {that_number}\n{comment}")

print("\n".join(result))
```

output:

```
Line: agrgb
This is a good planet
Line: 4f1g6
I like toast
Line: ew5je
I like horseriding
```

I splited each line with `maxsplit=2` to get those three parts that I'm interested in. Then I built my new line using f-string.

Comment: Is it possible to do this is a Paragraph also. I mean by detecting a set of words in a Paragraph and then adding a new line after 6 characters.

Comment: @CaptHash I didn't get you exactly but yes why not ? Ask a new question for that.